# Numer Of Basic Solution in Given Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Textbook denotes as follow:

$e^t$ and $e^{-t}$ are linearly independent basic solution of $y''-y =0$. Thus $c_1y_1 + c_2y_2$ is a general solution of $y''-y=0$

---

Question : Is the number of basic solution always depend on the highest order of differentiation of given equation?

There's no exact narrative given in my textbook so I am asking where could I find to specify the number of given Differential Equation to convincingly find out the general solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, an nth order linear differential equation with constant coefficients (such as the one in your example) always has $n$ linearly independent solutions. The argument is given in [these notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/diffeqdim.pdf).

The general idea is that you can associate a linear differential equation such as $ay+by'+cy''$ with a polynomial, which can then be factored (under the right circumstances). The factorisation of the associated polynomial guides you to solutions of the equation and you can prove that each solution is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of the space of solutions of a homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients is equal to its order.

To prove it one can use the fundamental solutions to show that there are that many independent functions. The independence will follow from the [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) determinant of their coefficients in the exponent being non-zero.

To show that they form a generating system consider the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) formed by a supposed solution and the fundamental solutions. Using the differential equation you get that their Wronskian is identically zero because the last row can be written as a linear combination of the others.